# When and where will all fixtures for the Bundesliga 3 be available for 2018/2019 season

Tags: football, bundesliga

I'm trying to find out exactly what date 1860 Munich are playing Hansa Rostock. Some websites say from the 1-4 March but without an exact day. Some websites only have a limited number of fixtures till September and some websites incorrectly show all games to be on Saturday.

Also what is the official website for Bundesliga 3 as when I search for it I get [bundesliga.com](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/) but with no option for the third league.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third tier of football in Germany is called [3. Liga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_football_league_system#Germany) (not Bundesliga 3), that's why you probably couldn't find their portal which is located on [DFB's website](https://www.dfb.de/3-liga/spieltagtabelle/?spieledb_path=%2Fcompetitions%2F4%2Fseasons%2Fcurrent%2Fmatchday%2F26), which shows that the **matchday 26** game TSV 1860 München - Hansa Rostock will be played on 1st and 4th of March, 2019.

[1860 München's website](http://www.tsv1860.de/de/Spiele_Loewen.htm) tells that this game will be played on 2nd of March, 2019.

[Hansa Rostock's website](https://www.fc-hansa.de/spielplan-tabelle.html) shows this date between 1st and 4th of March.

I would take all of these dates with a grain of salt because even [Bundesliga](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/bundesliga/matchday/2018-2019/?d=7) has scheduled the exact days only till its 6th matchday.

As I said, the official website of 3. Liga is the one on DFB's, so you should check it first. My observation is that as currently 2nd matchday is going on in 3. Liga and they have published exact dates and **times** till 10th matchday, then it's logical to assume that the exact dates and times of **matchday 26** won't be published eralier than 18th matchday. So, I guess it will be published somewhere around 7th and 10th of December.

Answer (score 2):

Now that league is my specialty. :)

The DFB (and DFL for the Bundesliga (1 & 2)) don't publish the exact match dates for the whole season right away. They only publish the week of each game day and call it *Rahmenspielplan* with the exact schedules set to be announced.

If you want to have official sources when it comes down to this league [dfb.de](https://www.dfb.de/3-liga/start/) is what you need. Or you'll want to visit portals like [liga3-online.de](https://www.liga3-online.de/) if you want independent news. As this league isn't one of the top domestic leagues English info will be hard to come by, though.

Anyway, usually the DFB will announce the exact match schedules for 3 or more match days a couple of weeks up to one or two months in advance (right now the first 10 match days are set, including the first game of Hansa vs 1860 in Rostock). They wait until the DFL guys announce theirs (or talk to the DFB guys about it in secret), because they try to avoid fans from rivaling clubs from different leagues to come across each others on the Autobahn or train stations. The DFL usually waits for the European competitions to adjust their dates accordingly (so a team playing in the Europa League on Thursday won't be playing on Friday).